# Unable to calculate the shape and scale parameters of weibull distribution from data simulated through either gems or simsurv in R

Tags: r, survival, simulation, weibull-distribution

I am trying to simulate survival data from a weibull distribution with shape = 1.3 and scale = 1.1. I am then fitting a weibull survival model to the data, to try and calculate back the values of 1.3 and 1.1. I am doing this in R.

To simulate the data, the packages I have tried to use to generate the survival times are [gems](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gems/vignettes/gems.pdf) and [simsurv](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/simsurv/simsurv.pdf). I want to use these packages, as opposed to rweibull, as eventually I will be simulating for more complex multistate data, and the hazard of the survival function must also be dependent on baseline covariates, etc. For comparison, I have also simulated survival times using rweibull.

To analyse the data, I am using the [flexsurvreg](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/flexsurv/versions/1.1.1/topics/flexsurvreg) function from the package flexsurv.

When I simulate data using *gems*, both the shape and scale are calculated incorrectly when fitting a weibull model back to the data. When I simulate data using *simsurv*, the shape is calculated correctly, but the scale is calculated incorrectly. When I simulate data using *rweibull*, both the shape and scale are estimated correctly. This final result makes me think it is the data that is being generated incorrectly, rather than *flexsurvreg* function not working properly.

I can see no reason why this should be the case, does anybody have an explanation for this? Does anybody have any other suggestions for generating survival data in R that allows different distributions to be defined and hazards to be adjusted at baseline?

A reproducible example is below. Note the packages will need to be installed if you do not already have them, which can be done by removing the # on the first four lines of code.

```
#install.packages("survival")
#install.packages("gems")
#install.packages("flexsurv")
#install.packages("simsurv")

library(survival)
library(gems)
library(flexsurv)
library(simsurv)

### Set seed
set.seed(101)

### Set number of patients
npat <- 10000

#####################################################
# Generate survival times using gems #
#####################################################

## Generate an empty hazard matrix
hf <- generateHazardMatrix(2)

## The states named "impossible" are the ones which I need to change the name of
hf

## Define the transitions as weibull for now
## I am leaving the transition from 1 -> 3 as "impossible' to that the structure is as planned


## Define the transitions as weibull
hf[[1, 2]] <- function(t, shape, scale) {
  (shape/scale)*(t/scale)^(shape - 1)}


## Generate an empty parameter matrix
par <- generateParameterMatrix(hf)

## Use the vector of scales in each transition hazard
par[[1, 2]] <- list(shape = 1.3, scale = 1.1)

## Generate the cohort
cohort <- simulateCohort(transitionFunctions = hf, parameters = par,
                         cohortSize = npat, to = 30)

## Turn event times into a dataframe and make the colnames not have any spaces in them, and 
## add a status variable
gems.cohort <- data.frame(cohort@time.to.state)
colnames(gems.cohort) <- c("state1","state2")
gems.cohort$status <- 1

head(gems.cohort)


#####################################################
# Generate survival times using simsurv #
#####################################################

## Creaet an empty dataset of baseline variables (used to define number of observations also)
bl  <- data.frame(id = 1:npat)

## Generate the data using simsurv (note that lambda is actually defined as 1/lambda)
simsurv.data <- simsurv(lambdas = (1/1.1), gammas = 1.3, x = bl, maxt = 30)
head(simsurv.data)



#####################################################
# Generate survival times using rweibull #
#####################################################

## Generate directly from rweibull
rweibull.data <- data.frame("eventtime" = rweibull(npat, shape = 1.3, scale = 1.1), "status" = rep(1, npat))



#####################################################
# Fit a parametric weibull model to each dataset #
#####################################################
gems.model <- flexsurvreg(Surv(state2, status) ~ 1, 
                           data = gems.cohort,dist = "weibull")



simsurv.model <- flexsurvreg(Surv(eventtime, status) ~ 1, 
                           data = simsurv.data,dist = "weibull")



rweibull.model <- flexsurvreg(Surv(eventtime, status) ~ 1, 
                             data = rweibull.data,dist = "weibull")


#####################################################
# Report the shape and scale #
#####################################################
gems.model
simsurv.model
rweibull.model

# Seems odd, but need to exponentiate the $coefficients to get the values reported from the model output
# This is odd, because these are not multiplicative effects on the baseline hazard
exp(gems.model$coefficients)
exp(simsurv.model$coefficients)
exp(rweibull.model$coefficients)

> exp(gems.model$coefficients)
   shape    scale 
1.357903 1.141540 
> exp(simsurv.model$coefficients)
   shape    scale 
1.288051 1.073805 
> exp(rweibull.model$coefficients)
   shape    scale 
1.302091 1.100632
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue when using simsurv is that the scale is actually defined like this: scale_sm = 1/(scale_rw^shape_sm), where _sm refers to the shape/scale according to simsurv, and _rw refers to the shape/scale according to rweibull or flexsurvreg.

Using the following code to generate the data:

```
simsurv.data <- simsurv(lambdas = 1/(1.1^1.3), gammas = 1.3, x = bl, maxt = 30)
```

The issue when using the gems package is answered in this question: [Generating weibull survival times using the built in rweibull function vs manually defining the hazard (using the gems package in R)](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/486729/generating-weibull-survival-times-using-the-built-in-rweibull-function-vs-manual)